# nginx enable authentication on specific port

Tags: nginx, password-protection

I am trying to protect the URL of my Kibana server with a password.

If I type http://192.168.1.2 in the browser, I am getting prompted for a username/password, but if I query the port 5601 directly via http://192.168.1.2:5601 then I can bypass the nginx proxy auth.

Note that both nginx and Kibana run on the same server.

I tried different combinations of "localhost" "0.0.0.0" or "127.0.0.1" as the listening source address but none of them worked. I can still easily bypass the proxy.

What am I doing wrong?

here's my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
server {
  listen 192.168.1.2:80;
  server_name 192.168.1.2;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:5601;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NGINX only listens on port 80 and does not prevent access to your application on port 5601. You should instead use a firewall to block access to the port itself. You could:

1. Place your server behind a firewall such as a router (blocks out all external network requests)
2. Install a firewall, like UFW, on the server itself.

Comment: I don't want to prevent access to the application listening on :5601, I want to add authentication.

Comment: You'll have to add authentication on kibana itself then. Here's a diagram of what you currently have: https://imgur.com/a/ZFS5P0T